# Getting value of checked CheckBox in vba access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Okay so I have couple of "checkboxes" in Access form. All I am trying to do is to get Checked Value of the checkbox.

By doing Me.Check271.Value it returns me 0 or -1. But

I want to get respected **label** of the checked CheckBox.

In picture below I want to msgbox the values which are checked:

What I am trying is:

MsgBox "Me.Check271.Parent"

[image]

Many Thanks

Comment: The solution to this has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637083/how-to-access-the-label-of-a-control-in-code
So this is judged as a 'trivial answer'?!?!? Want me to copy the entire solution and paste as the answer?

Comment: Yeah I made some changes to it and it worked. Sure paste it. I will mark your post as answer :)

Comment: I have to chuckle (or scratch my head, or grit my teeth...) at the 'rules' for postings. I have seen items placed on hold or downvoted because the poster 'didn't appear to do any research on their own' or 'question not clear', etc. My original 'Answer', which was a link, provided the solution (which was very verbose), but it was automatically(?) removed as being 'trivial'. Best of luck to your project!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Briefly, the following will work:

```
Check271.Controls.Item(0).Caption
```

Verbose Version: TextBoxes, ComboBoxes, ListBoxes, CheckBoxes have a maximum of 1 item in their controls collection (the attached label), but if the label isn't attached, they won't even have that, so .Controls(0) will throw an error.

The following will show Checkboxes that are 'checked'

```
Dim ctl         As Control
Dim blnChecked  As Boolean
Dim strChecked  As String

For Each ctl In Me.Section("Detail").Controls
    If ctl.ControlType = acCheckBox Then
        If ctl.Enabled = True Then
            Debug.Print ctl.Name & vbTab & ctl.Value
            If ctl.Value = vbTrue Then
                blnChecked = True
                strChecked = strChecked & ctl.Name & "; "
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next ctl
If blnChecked = True Then
    MsgBox "The following CheckBoxes were checked: " & strChecked, vbOKOnly, "Checked Boxes"
End If
```

Comment: Ok-Thank you. One more thing, if I have to check which of checkboxes are checked? So that I **only** get the labels of checked textboxes?

Comment: Thank you, What is "Detail"?

Comment: You mentioned you are using a FORM, which has multiole SECTIONS: header, detail, footer. I assume your checkboxes are in the DETAIL section, so I limit the search just to that section. If you have checkboxes in multiple sections, just make the code look like: 'Me.Controls' and it will search the entire form.  I narrowed to 'DETAIL' so as not to waste time. Hope this answers...

Comment: You are awesome!  Thank you. Just last question, Now that I have only "Name" in "strChecked":  
How can I have their label values as you just answered before.  
    
I tried this:    

           `If ctl.Value = vbTrue Then
                blnChecked = True
                strChecked = ctl.Name
                MsgBox strChecked.Controls.Item(0).Caption
                
            End If`

Comment: In the code you just posted, change to "MsgBox ctl.Controls.Item(0).Caption" -- not strChecked which I am betting is a string variable you defined.