# How to get label text from control?

Tags: ms-access, vba, controls

On my Access form I have an edit control and a combobox.  Each has a label that is attached to it on the form.

In the code, how can I fetch the text of the label for each control?  I want to produce a msgbox using the label's text.

I am thinking to do something like this [you can't do this, by the way]?

```
If IsNull(Me.EditControl) Then
   msgbox "My label's text is: " & me.EditControl.Label.text
Elseif IsNull(Me.ComboboxControl) Then
    msgbox "My label's text is: " & me.ComboboxControl.Label.text
End If
```

I would like to fetch the label without having to know the label's ID.

[I've read through this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637083/how-to-access-the-label-of-a-control-in-code), but it doesn't seem to work for me.  The intellisense doesn't recognize the construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The label can be referenced as item 0 in the parent control's `.Controls` collection, and the label's text is its `.Caption` property.

```vb
If IsNull(Me.EditControl) Then
    msgbox "My label's text is: " & Me!EditControl.Controls(0).Caption
Elseif IsNull(Me.ComboboxControl) Then
    msgbox "My label's text is: " & Me!ComboboxControl.Controls(0).Caption
End If
```

Comment: That was it!  I was missing the `!` part.  Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: Glad it worked.  But I don't understand why `!` was key.  I can refer to my combo box with either `Me.MyComboName` or `Me!MyComboName`

Comment: You can refer to the combobox that way, but NOT the label attached to the combobox

Comment: I think something else is going on.  `TypeName(Me.txtProj_members)` tells me *ComboBox*, `Me.txtProj_members.Controls(0).Name` shows me the `Name` of the associated label control, and then `Me.txtProj_members.Controls(0).Caption` shows me the label's `Caption` text.

Comment: Are you testing with Access VBA 2010?

Comment: Yes. (filler characters)