# Error using "MSForms.Control" type of variable

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-forms

I have been trying to run this code to get the caption of each control (a combobox in this example) on my form. But it keeps telling me "type mismatch". Please help. Thank you.

```
Private Sub Command266_Click()
    Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
    Dim x As Long
    
    x = 0
    
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        Select Case True
        Case TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.ComboBox
        MsgBox "control caption is" & ctrl.Caption, vbOKOnly, " test"
        End Select
    Next ctrl
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"MS Access forms" are **not** "MSForms". MSForms is a separate UI technology that can be used, for example, to create UI windows for Excel.

You need to use the types `Access.Control` and [`Access.ComboBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.combobox) instead. Unless you messed around with the order of references, you can just refer to them as `Control` and `ComboBox`.

In addition, `ComboBox` controls in Access don't have a `Caption` property. If you want to get the caption of the label associated with the combobox, you can [use the `Controls(0)` property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1637083/87698).

Thus, the following code should work:

```
Dim ctrl As Control
Dim lbl As Label

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    Select Case True
        Case TypeOf ctrl Is ComboBox
            Set lbl = ctrl.Controls(0)
            MsgBox "control caption is " & lbl.Caption, vbOKOnly, "test"
    End Select
Next ctrl
```

Comment: Access hides the VBIDE command for it, but you can still have a MSForms `UserForm` in an Access-hosted VBA project (the command is actually surfaced with Rubberduck). Access forms on the other hand, are _document modules_, like Excel worksheets are: they are owned and managed by the host application, and have a corresponding VBA code-behind module.